# Variable pulse train generation

Tags: 555, pulse

I need to generate a pulse train with 12 bit resolution, controlled by an MCU.

The duty cycle can be in the range of 30 - 40%, while the frequency (0.5 - 32 kHz) is what needs controlling with 12-bit resolution.

The pulse train is to be used to control a [Yaskawa Inverter](https://www.yaskawa.com/delegate/getAttachment?documentId=SIEPC71060618&cmd=documents&openNewTab=true&documentName=SIEPC71060618.pdf) which appears to operate under these parameters.

I think I have several options:

1. Find a chip that will generate this for me (controlled via SPI, I2C, etc).
2. Use a pulse generator like the 555, and find someway to vary the frequency using an output from the MCU - perhaps using the output from a DAC.

What is best way to do this?

Comment: Please explain what characteristics of the signal you want to be fixed and what characteristic you wish to vary with 12-bit resolution. Frequency? Duty factor? Also, what is the range of frequencies you need to produce? How precisely do you need to maintain the frequency or duty factor?

Comment: Your question is missing details such as the frequency, voltage, etc. Can we also presume that you mean that the pulse-width should be adjustable with 12-bit resolution? A 555 will not be suitable.

Comment: Please see update

Comment: I don't think you've thought this through yet. 12-bit is 4096 steps. 32 kHz / 4096 = 7.8 Hz per step. So the first two steps will be 0.5 and 8.3 Hz. Is that really what you want? I think another edit with some context is in order.

Comment: @Transistor, not sure why that would be a problem? Could you elaborate please

Comment: Question updated

Comment: It depends on the application. 0.5 to 8 Hz is a change of 1600% in one step so it seemed strange to me.

Comment: @Transistor, if each step has the same frequency increment, then you would have a linear ramp. Isn't that what's important?

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't clear in the original question and many applications require an equal step *ratio* - a musical scale for example. You also specified a minimum of 0.5 Hz which backed up my ratiometric (incorrect) hunch. If you had specified 0 to 32 kHz - and you probably will want to stop the motor sometime - I probably would have assumed a linear scale. Adequate specifications are important.

Comment: By equal step ratio, you mean x / x - 1 = same ratio, where x = step?

Comment: This cleared it up for me:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament

Comment: There isTimerblox tools from Linear which are very easy to use, just 2 resisters will configure duty cycle and frequency of the Pulse train. May be check LT6992.

Comment: What function will the pulse train drive in the controller? The manual says you can use it as the frequency reference for the controller,  as the PID feedback, as the PID setpoint, and as the motor speed input.  Which frequency you need depends on which function you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. The inverter provides several external speed control options.*

You are not constrained to 32 kHz.
Page 112 shows that the max pulse frequency can be set parameter H6-02 at anywhere between 1 kHz to 32 kHz (and as low as 100 Hz on some models). Setting a lower frequency may simplify the microcontroller requirements.

Your other option is to PWM the A1 or A2 input with a 5 V signal via an RC low-pass filter but set the parameter for the input scaling to twice the maximum speed you want. (This is because your 5 V micro can only give 5 V at 100% PWM into the 0 to 10 V input.)

Any micro with a PWM controller with ≥ 12 bits should be able to do this for you - including d'[Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/zero-due-mkr-family/analogwriteresolution/).

Note also that there's a Modbus interface so you can probably set and read the speed (and a load of other parameters) on serial comms thereby avoiding any analog circuitry.

Comment: So, let's say that I went with a max frequency of 2khz (I presume control over 0 - 2khz), how would I generate that? Are any of the options in the original question suitable?

Comment: Did you study the linked article?

Comment: The one I linked? I read the first paragraph, and this sentence in particular made me realise why one might think the ratio between intervals is important: "In other words, the ratios of the frequencies of any adjacent pair of notes is the same"

Comment: Are we on the same page now (i.e. have I understood you)?

Comment: No, I have one link in my answer to the Arduino analogWriteResolution() function which discusses PWM, resolution and gives sample code. Oh - I see we're carrying on two conversations. Yes, the equi-tempered scale would be one example.

Comment: Ahhh, yes I did take a look, and may indeed go with this method. However I would still be interested in knowing how I could generate a pulse train (i.e. varying frequency, not duty cycle)

Comment: [arduino+variable+frequency+generator](https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+variable+frequency+generator).

Comment: I guess not as complicated as I made it out to be.

Comment: [Arduino library "Timer1"](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/TimerOne)  would be a good way to tackle the task.  Use its [PWM function (example)](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/TimerOne/blob/master/examples/FanSpeed/FanSpeed.pde) for timer controlled PWM from 32Hz to 1MHz.

Comment: @JRE, but would I be able to vary the frequency, while keeping the duty cycle the same? As I understand it, with pulse train, it's the frequency which changes, not the duty cycle.

Comment: Yes, you can.  I "built" a test signal generator (square wave) with an Arduino Nano just a couple of days ago using this library.  The Timer1.pwm command lets you set duty cycle and frequency.  If you always want 50% duty cycle, then you set 50% duty cycle when you set the frequency.

Comment: And, seriously.  Use the PWM function.  If you hook into the interrupt and toggle the output yourself, you will get slow, unreliable switching times.  The digitalWrite is just **slow.** Using digitalWrite you'll be lucky to get above 50kHz.  With the PWM method, you get 1MHz reliably.

Comment: @JRE, the inverter goes up to 32khz, so wouldn't need anything more than that. In general, are such things done directly from the MCU (with PWM peripherals), or with additional hardware?

Comment: The Atmega has support for it built in to its timers.